# Casperjs can't open urls dynamically?

Tags: casperjs

I am trying to navigate to urls that are created from the script itself.

This sample code does not work as (I had) expected. Can't figure out why :(

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    viewportSize:{
        width:1024, height:768
    },
    pageSettings:{
        userAgent:'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_2) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.79 Safari/535.11'
    },
    verbose:true
});

casper.on('open', function (location) {
    console.log(location + ' loaded');
});

casper.start('http://www.google.com', function() {
    this.test.assertTitle('Google', 'Google homepage title is the one expected');
});

casper.mytest = '';

casper.then(function () {
    casper.mytest = 'http://www.yahoo.com';
});

casper.thenOpen(casper.mytest, function() {
    this.test.assertTitle('Yahoo', 'Yahoo homepage title is the one expected');
});

casper.run(function () {
        casper.exit();
    }
);
```

The result is that the second page does not load:

```
http://www.google.com loaded
PASS Google homepage title is the one expected
 loaded    
FAIL Yahoo homepage title is the one expected
#    type: assertTitle
#    subject: ""
#    expected: "Yahoo"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think, the reason for your problem is that at the moment, when you register `thenOpen` step for Yahoo the variable `casper.mytest` is empty. This value gets into the CasperJS's map of steps at this moment, and it does not matter that you change the source variable in the step before.

The blog post [Webscraping with CasperJS and PhantomJS](http://www.subelsky.com/2012/08/webscraping-with-casperjs-and-phantomjs.html) may be helpful as an example of fetching dynamically constructed urls.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, if I use this.open() inside then(){}, it works. It 's very unsettling though, since I fear it will probably lead to very ugly code as my project scales up :(

Comment: @johnjohn, some time ago I made a patch (not a small thing though) of CasperJS, which made it working in step-by-step (ad-hoc) way. You could probably do the same as appropriate for your needs. The problem with my version is that it was some time ago, and is now outdated, and I do not plan to port this to the latest CasperJS.